# How to create a sequence of numbers in java

Tags: java

I want to create a sequence of numbers in Java like this :

```
1234957203969304597600234960702349100903450234847456282934857697900389262454869346
```

I want to create 1000 numbers in the sequence.

How can I do it?

I tried to do like this :

```
String seq = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    seq = String.format("%d",i);
}
System.out.println(seq);
```

It does not work, it prints out:

> 999

Comment: When you do `seq = ` this assigns the new value by replacing the old one.

Comment: Do you want a String with a length of 1000 containing only digits, or you want to add 1000 numbers one after another? Since in your current for-loop (after changing `seq=` to `seq+=`) you'll have a sequence like this: `01234567891011...`, where numbers > 10 are actually two or three digits, not one. So the total length of your String for 1000 sequential numbers would be 2890.

Comment: thank you all God bless you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  sb.append(i);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

As a general note, while `str = str + someString;` will work, inside a loop it can quickly get out of hand. Try it with 10000 iterations and you'll see (large amounts of RAM & CPU consumed).

`StringBuilder` is better, if one really needs to build a string in this way, and it's always better performace-wise when one is appending to a character sequence more than a couple of times.

Answer (score 4):

You need to append it to the String. I suggest using a StringBuilder.

What you are doing is overwriting the String every time

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString(i);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Beat you by 10 seconds ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work, change `seq=String.format("%d",i);` into `seq+=String.format("%d",i);`.

A better way however, is to use a `StringBuilder` like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    sb.append(i);
}
String seq = sb.toString();
System.out.println(seq);
```

---

EDIT: Actually, this doesn't generate a String with length `1000`, since it adds like this: `012345678910...` (> 10 is two or three numbers instead of one).

So, instead try something like this using the `Random` class for a random number of `0-9`:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    sb.append(randomGenerator.nextInt(9));
}
String seq = sb.toString();
System.out.println(seq);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a stream of length 1000 with each digit being random, then try Math.random function.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing 999 because **you are always overwriting the string with the last value of the loop**, you need to append the data, not overwrite it over and over again...

## Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    sb.append(i);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```